# Android firebase chat sender and receiver gravity left and right not working

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm developing an android chat using firebase but I'm getting problem in assigning the gravity of the message. The message of sender is in left and the message of receiver is in the right.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mFirebaseAdapter1 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatModel, ChatMessageViewHolder>(ChatModel.class,
            R.layout.textview,
            ChatMessageViewHolder.class,
            ref_chatchildnode1) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ChatMessageViewHolder chatMessageViewHolder, ChatModel m, int i) {

            if (m.getSender().equals(LoggedInUser)) {

                chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setText(m.getMessage());
                chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.color.user));

            } else {

                chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setText(m.getMessage());
                chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.color.ae));
            }

        }
    };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter1);
    //mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter2);
    mFirebaseAdapter1.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            int friendlyMessageCount = mFirebaseAdapter1.getItemCount();
            int lastVisiblePosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the
            // user is at the bottom of the list, scroll to the bottom
            // of the list to show the newly added message.
            if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                    (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                            lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to do LinearLayout programmatically but nothing happen. Here is what I did:

```
if (m.getSender().equals(LoggedInUser)) {

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.weight = 1.0f;
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

    chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setText(m.getMessage());
    chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setLayoutParams(params);
    chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.color.user));

} else {

    chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setText(m.getMessage());
    chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.color.ae));

}
```

Please help me to contruct my code.

Comment: You can use two xmls with same views and different gravity. One is for messages from other users. The other one applies to the messages you send. So you can assign gravity more easily on the xml side.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can see 2 possible solutions... **The first one** try to work with two ViewHolders with firebaseUI (I don't know if can do it this) and **the second one** and the most easy, work with relative layout per row and put inside your bubble chat view, then use align parent right or parent left.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem.

here is what i did.

```
if (m.getSender().equals(LoggedInUser)) {

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.weight = 1.0f;
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

    chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setText(m.getMessage());
    chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setLayoutParams(params);
    chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.color.user));

} else {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.weight = 1.0f;
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

    chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setText(m.getMessage());
    chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setLayoutParams(params);
    chatMessageViewHolder.msg.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.color.ae));
}
```